# VB.NET Linebreak Changes

Tags: vb.net, language-design

Does anyone know if I can find a list of where the line break (`_`) is no longer required. So far I notice parameter lists and attributes now work without the line break char.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, it's called a *line continuation character*.

This is not a feature of the .NET Framework version, it's a feature of the compiler. The first version to support it is VB.NET 10, the one included with Visual Studio 2010.

The new feature is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336123.aspx), including a nice table listing where continuation is implicit.

> Visual Basic is a line-oriented language that uses clear, English-like syntax to enhance readability. But that often results in code that runs up against the 80-character-per-line limit, forcing developers to scroll a lot. You can use the underscore character to tell the compiler that it should keep processing the next line as part of the current one (that is, treat multiple physical lines as a single, logical line). But having to type underscores repeatedly has always been annoying, and in fact, for years the No. 1 feature request has been for the compiler to “just figure it out.”
>
> Well, in Visual Basic 2010, the compiler can. It now knows which tokens (such as commas, parentheses and operators) tend to occur right before the line-continuation character, and it inserts the character so developers no longer need to. For example, ending a Visual Basic statement with a comma is never legal; the compiler knows this, so when it sees a token stream that looks like {comma, enter}, it infers the presence of the line continuation character
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> [image]
>
> As you can see, there are more than 60 places where the language doesn’t require underscores. (In fact, none of the code samples in this article required the line-continuation character.) Of course, you can still use the underscore, so code from previous versions of Visual Basic will still compile as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for where you can break a line haven't changed.  You just no longer need the _ at all with the later compilers.